# How to create search box to grab results from a loop in a view ASP.NET Razor MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, search-box

I am trying to create a search box in order to search through the data within the loop, I am aware of `Html.BeginForm` however I am not targeting a controller and its action. I have a `foreach` loop in my code which gives me the data that I want.

I just would like the user to be able to search the data based on that loop. I hope this made sense.

I would appreciate bit of help or guidance for this matter. Thanks in advance

```
<div id="dialog-store" title="Store information">
    <span class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 0 0;"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-info" style="float: left;"></span></span>
    <div style="margin-left: 23px;">
        <legend class="legend">r</legend>   
        <hr />
        <br />

        @foreach (var item in Model.Stores)
        {
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.DisplayFor( modelItem => item.StoreName)
            </div>          

            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DisplayFor( modelItem => item.StoreNumber) 
            </div>  
        }
        <br />
        <br />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: May not be an answer but to speed up development I suggest, you may try jQuery based free grid components where lot of such functionality is already built which save you effort.

Comment: [It will help you](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)